# Not able to access the Android Wear Xamarin.Android template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently reinstalled Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and seem to not be able to access my Xamarin.Android Android Wear project template. It is not visible when I try to create a new project. I have installed all the requirements stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/wear/get-started/installation) too.

Is it possible to get the template somewhere or any fix for this issue? Has anyone else also faced a similar issue?

Comment: If you don't see the Wear template, review the [Installation and Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/wear/get-started/installation?tabs=windows) guide to double-check that you have installed a supported Android SDK.

Comment: I did that...have the updated versions of those.
But it still is not showing up :(

Comment: I have the following installed:  Android SDK Platform 28 (with Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image), Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2, Java JDK 1.8 (same as the one in the Installation guide)

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix

So I downgraded my VS Enterprise 2019 from v16.9 to v16.4, and I got the template back.
So it must be an issue with the new update.